# PHP - adjust time() to be divisible by 5

Tags: php, datetime, time, division

I'm using PHP's time() to set two dates (default values for two input fields):

- a start date, which should be the current time: `date('m/d/Y H:i', time());`
- a end date, which should be the current time + 2 hours: `date('m/d/Y H:i', time() + 60*60*2);`

How can I adjust both dates, so the minutes divide with 5?

For example, if the current time is *12/12/2012 **14:16***, I want to adjust it to **14:20**.
Or if the current time is *12/12/2012 **04:59***, I want to adjust it to **05:00**.

Comment: `date('m/d/Y H:i', strtotime('+2 hours', time()));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$time = ceil(time() / 300) * 300;

echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $time);
echo date('m/d/Y H:i', $time + 60 * 60 * 2);
```

Comment: @diEcho Divide by 300 (5 minutes), then round up (dropping floating point), then times back to 300.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other inbuilt function to achieve you problem , but  here is the my solution to your problem

```
<?php

    $minute = date('i'); 
    $divident = ceil($minute/5); 

    $new_minute = $divident  * 5; 
    $difference = $new_minute - $minute ; 
    date('m/d/Y H:i' ,time() + 60 * $difference   ); // first date 

    date('m/d/Y H:i' ,time() +  $difference * 60 +  (2 * 60 * 60)   ) // second date.
?>
```

I hope this helps :)

Prabeen